# ReSharper: Overload candidates covering half the screen

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

I recently installed ReSharper within Visual Studio 2017. Whenever I hover over method that has a lot of overloads, half my screen is being covered with suggested candidates.

This is rather impractical as I cannot keep editing the method that I put my cursor on nor can I select portions of the method, since the overlay covers the method in question.

Is there a setting within ReSharper where I could turn off this feature?
Maybe there is a setting that would even limit the number of rows?

Within ReSharper's IntelliSense settings, I disabled `Automatically show parameter info after x-milliseconds`, as well as `Display signature at once`. Prior to that I checked that `Limit the number of candidates to 5` was active.
However, none of the options had any effect on the resulting screenshot below:

[image: Screenshot of half the screen covered with possible candidates - removed the code and possible candidates - hopefully this doesn't make it even more confusing than it is already ;-)]
`Screenshot of half the screen covered with possible candidates - removed the code and possible candidates - hopefully this doesn't make it even more confusing than it is already ;-)`

[image: Updated Screenshot]

Comment: Why is ReSharper showing overloads at all, is it because you are writing ambiguous code? In any case, ReSharper and Visual Studio will show intellisense popups when you hover over code. The only way to get rid of those while you're writing code is to move the mouse.

Comment: Could you perhaps post a screenshot with made-up information about what you're seeing? The reason for my question is that I'm unable to get the same intellisense, when I hover over a method with overloads I get a small popup that says things like "void Program.Foo(string o) (+ 1 overload)".

Comment: Basically, why is it **suggesting** anything? Are you actually writing code, then a full stop, and the intellisense popup is what is showing? Or are you hovering over code with a problem, like ambiguous parameter lists, missing conversions, missing parameters? In that case ReSharper will show a list of possible candidates, **but that is by design**. By hovering over an identifier or something in your code, ReSharper will leap into action and try to help you. If you don't want help, don't ask for help. **Move the mouse**.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen, yes, let me post some more meaningful screenshots :-) I am seeing all available overloads because I am copying the line in question from a different class, so the parameters for the method are not correct. Let me post the screenshots quick :-)

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen please let me know if this screenshot explains it better :-) Thank you for your help :-)

Comment: Yes, and then this is by design. You've got broken code, you're hovering over it, ReSharper tries to help you, it's not its fault that you have a badly designed API (lots and lots of overload candidates). So no, there is no easy way to fix this short of disabling the popup altogether (which I believe you cannot do), or just **move the mouse**.

Comment: Right. However, if I would like to highlight part of the broken code, I need to **move the mouse** within the broken code, which will then trigger the popup. After disabling ReSharper, VS shows a much smaller list, though.